# JQuery ajax calls collision using Play! framework

Tags: ajax, jquery, playframework

When some action is invoked in my page, I make two ajax calls (A, B) to two different methods on my server.
Most of the times each request gets its matching response, but here and there both requests gets the same response! (of one of the requests - A,A or B,B)

The Ajax calls are made using JQuery and the server methods are implemented using Play! framework (in java).

Does anyone have any idea why does it happen and how to resolve it?

Thanks!

Ajax Call A:

```
var renderTypePreviewPageRoute = jsRoutes.com.eyeview.connectad.controllers.solutions.FeedLibrary.getFeedTypePreviewPage(feedHashId, feedType);

    // Makes an ajax call that gets the rendered solution page
    $.ajax({

        // Sets the route (URL) of the server call
        url:renderTypePreviewPageRoute.url,

        // Sets the method (GET / POST) of the server call
        type:renderTypePreviewPageRoute.method,

        //data:{ hashId: feedHashId, feedType: feedType, withPreview: withPreview }-->

        // In case of success
        success:function(result) {

            var typePreviewElement = $('#typePreviewSection');

            // Set the feed preview section html content to the rendered content got from the server
            typePreviewElement.html(result);

            typePreviewElement.removeClass('hidden');

            $('#feedPreviewGrid tr:eq(1)').removeClass('hidden');

            if ($('#feedPreviewSection').is(':visible')){

                typePreviewElement.show('blind');
            }

            var feedURL = urlEle.val();
            if (waitForFileTypePreview && feedURL != "") {
                feedEditNS.renderFilePreviewSection(true);
            }
        },

        // In case of failure
        error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

            // Shows the error message
            showError(xhr.responseText);

            // Clears the preview section
            feedEditNS.clearTypePreviewSection();

            var feedURL = urlEle.val();
            if (waitForFileTypePreview && feedURL != "") {
                feedEditNS.renderFilePreviewSection(true);
            }
        }
```

Ajax Call B:

```
var renderFilePreviewPageRoute = jsRoutes.com.eyeview.connectad.controllers.solutions.FeedLibrary.getFeedFilePreviewPage(feedHashId);

    // Makes an ajax call that gets the rendered solution page
    $.ajax({

        // Sets the route (URL) of the server call
        url:renderFilePreviewPageRoute.url,

        // Sets the method (GET / POST) of the server call
        type:renderFilePreviewPageRoute.method,

        // In case of success
        success:function(result) {

            // Set the feed preview section html content to the rendered content got from the server
            $('#filePreviewSection').html(result);

            // Shows the feed preview section
            $('#verticalLine').show('blind');
            $('#leftShadow').show('blind');
            $('#rightShadow').show('blind');
            $('#feedPreviewSection').show('blind');

            feedEditNS.createDataTable(withHeaders);

            waitForFileTypePreview = false;
        },

        // In case of failure
        error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

            // Shows the error message
            showError(xhr.responseText);

            // Clears the preview section
            feedEditNS.clearFilePreviewSection();

            waitForFileTypePreview = false;
        }
```

Comment: It's an error in your Javascript code, to me. Show us the relevant lines

Comment: Hi! thanks for the quick answer. Added my two Jquery ajax calls above.

Comment: And if its a mistake in the code how does it work most of the times, and only in few cases i get the same response?...

Comment: Hmmm this way it's hard to tell. First, make sure you actually fire two different HTTP requests. You can by Chrome inspector or Firebug extension for FF. Then, in the same panel, examine the responses to double check they are different. Finally, explain **exactly** why you state *they both return the same data*. Is it a UI thing? Did you check with the debugger?

Comment: I inspected both answers in both Chrome and FF. In both cases i saw two event fired. most of the times when i inspected the responses I saw there are two different contents. But in few other cases i saw the same content in the response (even though it went to two different URL - REST)

Comment: Can you update your question with the *offending* URLs and the duplicated response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not resolve the problem.
So, I ended up combining both calls to one call to a single server side method.
This method returned a JSON object containing both calls answers.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact issue (3'ish years later...)  I am still not sure what the real problem is, but as a workaround I ended up using `setTimeout()` inside my Angular controller.

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myRestApi) {

    $scope.restCallOne = function() {
        myRestApi.callOne().then(
            // handle result one
        );
    };

    $scope.restCallTwo = function() {
        myRestApi.callTwo().then(
            // handle result two
        );
    };

    // loads each time the view is shown
    // *** race condition when calling consecutively without a delay ***
    //$scope.restCallOne();
    setTimeout($scope.restCallOne, 100);
    $scope.restCallTwo();

});
```